# Derive an algorithm to determine convex combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

## Problem statement

Given is the density matrix of a spin-1/2 system which was set up in a state of superposition
$$
\varrho = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now I'd like to find convex combinations, such that
$$
\varrho = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} p_i \; \chi_i \chi_i^\dagger
$$
where $p_i \in [0,1]$ and $\chi_i \in \mathbb{C}^2$. Furthermore the $\chi_i$ need to be normalized, i.e.
$$
\| \chi_i \| = 1
$$
and also
$$
\sum_i p_i = 1
$$
The $\chi_i$ don't need to be orthogonal.

I don't even know where to start, because this case is not as easy as finding linear combinations, where there is no such condition as $p_i \in [0,1]$. How do I satisfy this condition?

## Remarks

$(\cdot)^\dagger$ is the hermite conjugate.

$\chi_i \chi_i^\dagger$ denotes a matrix product. Example:
$$
\chi_i = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\implies \chi_i \chi_i^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Is there some normalisation condition on the  $\chi_i$? As the problem is stated, it seems you can turn any linear combination into a solution by rescaling the $\chi_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to add the fact that the $\chi_i$ need to be normalized. At least they don't need to be orthogonal.

Comment: Do you additionally require $\sum_i p_i = 1$? This is the usual notion of convex combination. If not then you can just take linear combination and split up each term - e.g. $3.5 m$ can be split as $1 m + 1m + 1m + 0.5m$.

Comment: Thank you for improving my question. Indeed the sum of the $p_i$ needs to be $1$ as the $p_i$ are the probabilities of being in states $\chi_i$ and the total probability can't exceed $100\%$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use unitary diagonalization to find such a decomposition, and the fact that $\varrho$ is a density matrix should guarantee that it is in fact a convex combination. In particular we need the fact that $\varrho$ is positive-semidefinite Hermitian with trace $1$ - according to Wikipedia this is true for anything one would call a density matrix, and it is certainly true for your example.

Apply the spectral theorem to $\varrho$: since it is Hermitian, it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ with corresponding real eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. We can thus write $\varrho = \sum_{i=1}^2 \lambda_i v_i v_i^\dagger$.

Now, why does this decomposition satisfy your convexity requirements?

- $\Vert v_i \Vert = 1$ because the $v_i$ form an ortho-*normal* basis
- $\lambda_i \ge 0 $ and $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$ (and thus $\lambda_i \le 1$) because $\varrho$ is positive-semidefinite Hermitian with trace $1$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is a rather "trivial" solution. In fact I want to find **all** convex combinations.